# Implement webdav client on android using libcurl

Tags: android, curl, libcurl, webdav

I'd like to implement libcurl function in android. Original curl command is below:

```
curl -k  --user "username:password" --header "Depth: 1" --data "data" -X PROPFIND https://device_ipaddr/device_name > /tmp/AiStorageList
```

Following is my code in android jni:

```
CURL *curl;
CURLcode res;
std::string content;

curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
curl = curl_easy_init();

if(curl) {
    struct curl_slist *headers = NULL;
    char *data="data";
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Depth: 1");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,headers);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://device_ipaddr/device_name");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, "username:password");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PROPFIND");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, data);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, Post_Response);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &content);

    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    LOGD("res: %d\n", res);
    LOGD("content = %s \n", content.c_str());
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}

curl_global_cleanup();
return 0;
```

Here is Post_Response function:

```
static long Post_Response(void *data, int size, int nmemb, std::string &content)
{
    long sizes = size * nmemb;
    std::string temp((char*)data,sizes);
    content += temp;

    return sizes;
}
```

I always get the res "1", it means the error occured while excuting curl_easy_perform, and the content is also empty.
Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: why curl? why C? why not java? why not Apache HttpClient or HttpUrlConnection?

Comment: I tried "sardine" and "jackrabbit" library before for android webdav client but stuck in https issue...